# how to solve Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

i am trying to connect my telegram bot and telegram bot api to my project and when i run i face to this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:151)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:977)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.facilities.TelegramHttpClientBuilder.build(TelegramHttpClientBuilder.java:31)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.DefaultAbsSender.<init>(DefaultAbsSender.java:79)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot.<init>(TelegramLongPollingBot.java:20)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot.<init>(TelegramLongPollingBot.java:16)
```

any one know how can i fix it?

this i s my test code

```
public static void main(String []args) {
        ApiContextInitializer.init();
        TelegramBotsApi botsApi= new TelegramBotsApi();
        try {
            botsApi.registerBot(new Bot());
        } catch (TelegramApiRequestException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

i trying to remove extra httpclient librarys and it not work. any one can tell me how fix this error?

Comment: One or more of the libraries used is not the version expected by the code causing this exception to be thrown.

Comment: how can i find this libraries. i don't know what to do?

Comment: The hint is clear INSTANCE. The problem is to look for this word. Usually it is caused by the last throw and it is the org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory

Comment: is the library caused this problem or my project?